# Can I control a 1500-watt electric wall heater with a motion-sensing switch?

Tags: electrical, switch, heater, motion-sensor

I want to buy a 1500-watt electric wall heater with a built-in fan to supplement heat in a basement room. I want to wire it to an occupancy-sensor wall switch that I can turn off entirely in the summer or leave set to "auto" in the winter.

My concern is that I can't find a motion-sensor switch that advertises capability to handle 1500 watts.

Both 120 and 240-volt models of the heater are available.

How can I make this work?

Answer (score 2):

Leviton ODS15-IDG

Rated 1800 watts at 120 volts

Single Gang Space

$45 at Amazon

Comment: Wow, I had no idea *nifty* switches went up that high; this sounds much easier.

Comment: That looks about right. Do I have to worry that the wall heater will activate the infrared sensor?

Comment: @MichaelH What a great question. The sensor will have some adjustment on it. They expect that you will have pets and not want them to set it off. It should adjust to the heat that is rising, and see it as background noise, allowing it to turn off.

Comment: I think what I want is actually the [IPP0R-1FW](http://www.leviton.com/OA_HTML/ProductDetail.jsp?partnumber=IPP15-1FW&section=38557&minisite=10251) switch. It appears that it requires a person to turn it on, but it can either by turned off manually or will time out after no motion is detected and turn itself off. Also it doesn't monitor light in the room, so it will work the same in the light and the dark. Hard to tell though--Leviton's search tool is inadequate for the size of their inventory!

Comment: Or the Cooper [OSW-P – 120/277V PIR](http://www.cooperindustries.com/content/public/en/lighting/controls/products/occupancy_sensors/ws_sensors/pir/120_277_pir_sgl.brands.lighting!controls!greengate!occupancy_sensors!wall_switches!pir_passive_infrared.html), which is also good to 1800 watts.

Answer (score 0):

Use a [24 Volt Occupancy Sensor](https://www.google.com/search?q=24v%20opconecy%20sensor&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#q=%2224v%20occupancy%20sensor%22) in conjunction with a thermostat.

Comment: This will provide for an elegant solution, the only issue is that you would still need the relay that can deal with 1500 watts. It could be included in the thermostat. It would then also need to be wired into a power source. If you are looking for a multi-room, or multi-location control, and are willing to wire in the 120 V relay, this is the right answer.